# M.2 NVMe SSD with USB-C to M.2 adapter

Tags: ssd, usb-storage, usb-c, nvme, m.2

I have a USB-C to M.2 (key-B) adapter that uses the chipset JMS580 from JMicron. I'm connecting my KingSpec M.2 NVMe SSD (PCIe Gen3 NE series) but it is not recognized by any computer. I can see the USB device, but no disk is recognized.

I started to look at the JMS580 chipset and it looks like it is meant to work with the SATA interface. However, my SSD seems to be PCIe only. I think the M.2 standard is a jungle. The SSD and the USB adapter have the same connection (M.2 Key-B) but could they still only be supporting different protocols and thus not be compatible?

JMS580 chipset: https://www.jmicron.com/file/download/905/jms580.pdf

SSD disk: https://www.kingspec.com/product/nvme-pcie-ssd-ne-2280mm.html

Comment: M.2 can be SATA and NVMe.  What is the **exact** model of the adapter you are using?

Comment: @Ramhound The chipset of the adapter is JMS580. The adapter is this: https://fyndiq.se/produkt/ngff-for-m-2-ssd-till-usb3-1-typ-c-converter-adapter-card-jms580-high-performance-controller-chipset-support-sata3-6gb-us-bbd4573761364420/ sorry for the link in Swedish.

Comment: The product description, in very clear text, indicates it only supports SATA drives. Purchase an M.2 adapter that supports NVMe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a USB-C to M.2 (key-B) adapter that uses the chipset JMS580 from JMicron. I'm connecting my KingSpec M.2 NVMe SSD (PCIe Gen3 NE series) but it is not recognized by any computer. I can see the USB device, but no disk is recognized.

The USB M.2 adapter you purchased only supports SATA M.2 drives.

> I think the M.2 standard is a jungle.

It's not a complicated jungle.  M.2 is an interface which supports multiple standards like SATA and NVMe

Comment: I think what is confusing me is that I have understood it as M.2 comes in a key-B and a key-B+M format for the two different protocols. However that does not seem to be the case. Thanks for your reply.